# Get district boundaries for Tokyo

Tags: geojson, data, kml, japan

I am looking for district boundaries (what OSM puts at level 9) for Tokyo major Wards (level 7 in OSM).

I have found on OSM and affiliated websites some of the district boundaries, but hardly all.

Example : Shinjuku which is a ward , so level 7. OSM has almost no more granular boundaries for the districts contained inside this ward.

Where can I get this data?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Shinjuku is a city in Tokyo prefecture.

Comment: There is one in [e-Stat](https://www.e-stat.go.jp/en) prepared by Statistics Bureau of Japan and the direct link to Shinjuku dataset is [here](https://www.e-stat.go.jp/gis/statmap-search/data?dlserveyId=A002005212015&code=13104&coordSys=2&format=shape&downloadType=5).